# org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient.win has missing constraints com.sun.jna.*

Tags: eclipse-plugin, apache-httpcomponents

-> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient.win; bundle-version="4.5.13.v20211010-1849"
org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient.win [525]
Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.sun.jna; version="[4.4.0,5.0.0)"

I am updating eclipse 4.23 and java 11. everything was till maven build and all but I am just trying to launch my application but this issue is facing while running app.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOFTP.png)

Comment: That is saying `org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient.win` wants a version of `com.sun.jna` less than 5.0.0 - but from Eclipse 4.20 onwards the version of com.sun.jna is 5.x. Eclipse now uses org.apache.httpcomponents.client5.httpclient5